# Killing/Creating new session everytime a request is sent?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new with python and have been playing with sending and getting requests with the requests module. However, I cannot figure out how to either kill or create a new session everytime a POST request is made. Here is the function I am using:

```
def sendRequestTest():

    try:
        session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
        login_data = {'email': EMAIL, 'password': PASSWD, 'username': USERNAME, 'first_name': NAME}
        login = session.post(SIGNUP_URL, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
        session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
        cookies = login.cookies
        login_text = json.loads(login.text)
        print(login_text)
    except:
        print("An connection error has occured.")
```

I have tried adding session.close() to the end of the function, but got an indentation error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Python is very picky about indentation. When you added `session.close()`, did you make sure its indentation (# spaces or # tabs) is same as that of `try`?

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure that a new session is created each time by initializing it in the method.

```py
import requests

def sendRequestTest():
    session = requests.Session()  # this will create a new session

    try:
        session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': req.cookies['csrftoken']})
        login_data = {'email': EMAIL, 'password': PASSWD, 'username': USERNAME, 'first_name': NAME}
        login = session.post(SIGNUP_URL, data=login_data, allow_redirects=True)
        session.headers.update({'x-csrftoken': login.cookies['csrftoken']})
        cookies = login.cookies
        login_text = json.loads(login.text)
        print(login_text)
    except:
        print("An connection error has occured.")
```

If you need to modify the session before sending the request, you can pass it to the `sendRequestTest` method as a variable and [create the session instance using a context manager](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects):

```py
import requests

def sendRequestTest(session):
    # ...

def make_fresh_session_request():
    with requests.Session() as session:
        # The session only exists *inside* of this "with" statement.
        # You can perform any setup of the session instance
        # you might need in here...

        sendRequestTest(session)

    # Outside of the "with" block, the session has been closed
```